# ngx-charts-bar-horizontal data label formatting

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-charts

I'm using **ngx-charts** more exactly **bar-horizontal**. What I'm trying to do is to format data label and add % at the end.
I have tried to use **[xAxisTickFormatting]** but it doesn't work because, from what I noticed, my values are not on **ngx-charts-x-axis** but on **ngx-charts-series-horizontal**.

ngx-charts used as bellow:

```
<ngx-charts-bar-horizontal 
*ngIf='givesEnergyChartData && givesEnergyDataColorScheme'  
[scheme]="givesEnergyDataColorScheme"
[results]="givesEnergyChartData"
[gradient]="gradient"
[xAxis]="showXAxis"
[yAxis]="showYAxis"
[legend]="showLegend"
[view]="viewGiveEnergy"
[showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
[showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
[showDataLabel]="showDataLabel">
</ngx-charts-bar-horizontal>
```

Also I have tried to format on data array (I know it was stupid, but I have tried:) )

```
this.givesEnergyChartData = this.statistic.givesEnergyData.map(
 s => {
   return { name: s.name, value: s.count } 
 });
```

by adding for value: s.count **+ '%'**.

So, what should I do to format the data labels and add '%' after values?

[here is my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NvRO.jpg)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this.

```
<ngx-charts-bar-horizontal 
*ngIf='givesEnergyChartData && givesEnergyDataColorScheme'  
[scheme]="givesEnergyDataColorScheme"
[results]="givesEnergyChartData"
[gradient]="gradient"
[xAxis]="showXAxis"
[yAxis]="showYAxis"
[legend]="showLegend"
[view]="viewGiveEnergy"
[showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
[showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
  [dataLabelFormatting] = "formatDataLabel"
[showDataLabel]="showDataLabel">
</ngx-charts-bar-horizontal>
```

and

```
  formatDataLabel(value )
  {
    return value + '%';
  }
```

Comment:  Be ware: for pie-chart it is `[labelFormatting]`, but this does NOT get triggered . What is kind of strange is the fact that this `dataLabelFormatting` is defined as a two-way input binding whether it feels more righteous to use an output event emitter!?

Answer (score 1):

You need this param [yAxisTickFormatting] and function like this in .ts file:

chart.component.ts

```
  percentTickFormatting(val: any) {
    return val.toLocaleString() + '%';
  }
```

chart.component.html

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical
  [view]="view"
  [results]="chartData"
  [xAxis]="true"
  [yAxis]="true"
  [legend]="true"
  [showXAxisLabel]="true"
  [showYAxisLabel]="true"
  [yAxisTickFormatting]="percentTickFormatting"
>
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
```

Comment: I want to start my y axis min value from 5, used [yAxisTickFormatting] and returned val +5 in functn but the chart data is not mapping proper ..at 11th tick chart peak value is 6...Also tried yScaleMin=5 ...wrong data...Any idea to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using **querySelector** and **innerHTML** like that:

```
 document.querySelectorAll(text.textDataLabel).innerHTML += '%';
```

Answer (score -1):

I add this code to CSS file for change the text style:

```
::ng-deep .ngx-charts .tick text {
    text-anchor: start;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```